# Accessing other contract variables(address)

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, truffle-contract

I'm creating a marketplace, which will have two token contracts representing currencyToken and assetToken. I've set separate owner's for both of the token contracts, in their constructor. But when I'm trying to access those two addresses from my exchangeContract, it is throwing an error:

`' Error: Member "CTOwner" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract CToken) '`

I've tried by creating getter functions for both the contract's, still the result is same.

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: May you post the code of your contract?